# Identifying ties in a different column of a rank in R

Tags: r, rank

I am working with R.

I have a set of data that looks like this.

```
principal    percentage     ranked
love            25            1
love            25            2
love            22            3
love            21            4
love            20            5
table           30            1
table           20            2
table           19            3
table           18            4
table           5             5
```

So, I need to know if the words that are in the 1 and second position in the rank are tied or not in the percentage column.

For example, I would like to have an output like this.

```
principal    tie
love         TRUE
table        FALSE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(principal) %>%
  summarise(tie = percentage[match(1, ranked)] == percentage[match(2, ranked)])

#   principal tie  
#  <chr>     <lgl>
#1 love      TRUE 
#2 table     FALSE
```

Similar alternatives will be -

```
#2.
df %>% 
   group_by(principal) %>% 
   summarise(tie = percentage[ranked == 1] == percentage[ranked == 2])

#3.
df %>%
  arrange(principal, ranked) %>%
  group_by(principal) %>%
  summarise(tie = percentage[1] == percentage[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: thanks to valuable comment of akrun_master! removed `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)

# helper function to coalesce by column
coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
  return(coalesce(df[1], df[2]))
}

            
df %>% 
  group_by(principal) %>% 
  mutate(ties = percentage[1] == percentage[2], TRUE, FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(Comments = coalesce_by_column(ties))
```

Output:

```
  principal Comments
  <chr>     <lgl>   
1 love      TRUE    
2 table     FALSE
```